# Почему scanf() просит ввести значение переменной 2 раза?

Tags: c, поток-ввода, scanf

Делаю лабораторную работу, в которой требуется введение только целых чисел. Проверка на соответствие типов данных кое-как работает через while. Беда в том, что когда ввожу значение с точкой, программа говорит, что "ерунда, давай по новой" и делает это с первого раза, работает так, как и хотелось бы (ввела double - try again). Но, чтобы считалось целочисленное значение, приходиться его вводить по два раза (ввела int - enter - ввела int - enter и только тогда оно переходит к считыванию следующего элемента массива). Искала, пробовала всякие "очистители" буфера, но не заработало. Вот кусочек, который не пашет:

```
void Matrix_input(int **matrix, short lines_numb, short columns_numb)
{
    for (short i = 0; i < lines_numb; i++)
    {
        for (short j = 0; j < columns_numb; j++)
        {
            printf("Element[%hd][%hd] = ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
             while (scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]) != 1){
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("Wrong type. We need only integer numbers. Try again\n");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Но ведь в этом коде вы просите ввести число многократно - первый раз перед циклом while, второй раз в цикле, третий раз - в его теле при неверном вводе, после чего, заметим, у вас опять будет запрос ввода в заголовке цикла... Зачем?

Comment: Убрала в теле цикла запрос на повторный ввод, спасибо. Теперь в случае, если сначала вводиться некорректное значение, то потом корректное принимается с первого раза (ввела double - enter - try again - ввела int - enter - считало). Но если ввожу сразу int, то просит ввести все равно 2 раза.

Comment: Вообще, если введено неверное значение - надо считать из буфера ввода все до `\n` - иначе несчитанный символ лежит в буфере и вновь и вновь дает ошибку. Как вы вводите число с точкой и при этом у вас не идет бесконечный вывод "...Try again" - я что-то не понимаю... Ну, а так - вы теперь все равно просите его вводить два раза: перед циклом и в цикле.

Comment: Если убрать fflush(stdin), то будет бесконечный вывод. А где в цикле я прошу? В условии?

Comment: `fflush` для `stdin` - это UB.

Comment: А чем его заменить можно?

Comment: Уберите строку `scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);` и `fflush(stdin);`. А внутри тела `while` напишите (неважно до или после вывода об ошибке) `scanf("%*[^\n]\n");`

Comment: Работает. Спасибо огромное Вам:)

Comment: Но это не конечное решение, потому что при вводе `123abc` будут проблемы...

Comment: Пока что по ТЗ это не требуется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
> while (scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]) != 1){
> ```

Сколько раз вызвал, столько и просит.